# Segmentation fault on global std::string variables with g++ 3.4 and g++ 4.7

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, stdstring

I have the following code:
main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string getString();
int main()
{
 cout<<getString()<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include <string>
const static std::string s="test";
std::string getString()
{
 return s;  //segmentation fault
 //return "test"; works 
}
```

I am compiling mylib.cpp with g++ 3.4.6 and main.cpp with g++ 4.7.2

 If mylib is linked statically segmentation fault error occurs, but if it is linked dynamically no errors occur.

Does any one have an explanation for what is happening.
this problem occurs only with std::string.

static link:

```
$ g++34 mylib.cpp -c (tried also $ g++34 mylib.cpp -c -nostdlib)
$ g++47 main.cpp mylib.o
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault
```

dynamic link

```
   $ g++34 mylib.cpp  -fpic -c
   $ g++34 -shared -o libs.so mylib.o
   ...
   $ g++47 main.cpp -Wall -ls -L.
   $ ./a.out
   test
```

Comment: "I am compiling mylib.cpp with g++ 3.4.6 and main.cpp with g++ 4.7.2". Do you want a disaster? Because that's how you get a disaster.

Comment: No, I wrote this example as simplification of an issue I am facing with my project,
The libraries are already compiled with g++ 3.4, I want to link my executable with these libraries to avoid recompilations, just std::string is generating errors, I tried with integers, std::vector and other types, no errors occur.

Comment: You either compile your executable with the older g++, or get the libraries recompiled with a newer g++. No one can guarantee you that any other option will work. You may get away with it sometimes. Or you may not.

Comment: Do we have always to compile the executable with the same version of compiler of the library?

Comment: Theoretically not, but we need to make sure ABI has not changed between the versions. You may try to derive ABI compatibility from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). I cannot understand this document. Theoretically your versions seem to be compatible, but in practice, who knows.

Comment: Is there a declaration for `getString()`?

Comment: Programs link to shared libraries compiled by different versions of the compiler all the time (which is why every program you compile with a new version of the compiler does not immediately break).  Are you sure both are using the same libstdc++? Does linking the library as a `.a` rather than `.o` work?

Comment: I didnt use header files just declaration in main.cpp

Comment: I tried with .a same issue. No i am not sure about the same libstdc++.

Comment: I edited my post, I tried -nostdlib flag for the library)

Comment: @mahmoud There is basically no way you can make this guaranteed to work. g++4.7 and its matching libstdc++ does not have any guarantee that it will work with mixing in things you compiled with g++3.4.6

Comment: Do you have any reference that shows the incompatibility? 
According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) page libstdc++ should be compatible.
Could it be a bug in the compilers?